# RoutingError problems with Webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

I'm currently rewriting a website in Rails. I've written a model that maps the old static URLs to the new ones and in the application controller I'm trapping RoutingErrors to call a method that looks for a new URL that maps to the old one. This works perfectly well in the applicaion itself; if I visit http://localhost:3000/home.htm it will redirect to http://localhost:3000/home, but I can't get the Cucumber / Webrat tests I've written to pass as I always get an error like this.

```
When I try to go to the old noticeboard          
  #features/step_definitions/redirection_steps.rb:7
  No route matches "/noticeboard.htm" with {:method=>:get} (ActionController::RoutingError)
  (eval):2:in `visit'
  ./features/step_definitions/redirection_steps.rb:8:in `/^I try to go to the old (.+)$/'
  features/old_urls.feature:26:in `When I try to go to the old noticeboard'
```

Obviously it's most important that the code actually works, and it does redirect correctly in the browser but I'd like the tests to pass too. Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever resolve this? I have been having a lot of issues with the visit method in webrat. This turned out to be having RAILS_ENV=development in my environment.